# Best way to get the OID of an order created at TradeHill?

Tags: tradehill

I'm working on my first trading script using the TradeHill API.

I find it pretty annoying that the OID of an order isn't returned to you when you create a new buy/sell order.

How exactly can you get the OID of a freshly created order? I'm thinking that you will have to have a list of orders before it is created and compare this with the new list after the order.

You must then find the new OID in the list?

Is this the only way?

Comment: Write tradehill (support@tradehill.com) and suggest they return it in their API call. The more they hear this, the more likely it is to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must keep a record of your orders and compare them with the returned list. Alternatively, you can sort the returned list according to date. The order you posted is the most recent.